# Browser stuck loading when I enter credentials for phpmyadmin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, mysql

I've been trying to set up a PHP development environment on my Linux machine here, I am using xampp and at I was able to enter PHPMyAdmin without entering credentials, now I set a password for `root` in the PHPMyAdmin dashboard and modified `config.inc.php` changing the line with:

```php
$cfg['servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

to

```php
$cfg['servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

also entering my password for the database too there, The line above is what seems to be the issue, When it's set to `config` I can enter PHPMyAdmin without a password.

How do I fix the problem so I can log in to PHPMyAdmin securely without the browser being stuck loading?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is how I can fix the problem.